# Import a playbook into another playbook without its' defined hosts

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible to create a playbook that includes a different playbooks as one of its' tasks.

To clarify, the playbook is meant to deploy Linux servers, and one of the steps is to clone a git repository.

When importing it (I tried using `import_tasks`, `include_tasks`, `import_playbook`, and `include_playbook`), Ansible returns the following error:

`ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, gather_facts`

Sure enough, when I edit the git playbook and remote the `hosts` statement, the import works without issue.

However, the git cloning is also meant to run independently (to keep said repository in sync), and therefore must include the `hosts` directive as well.

What I'm essentially looking for is a way to import a playbook's tasks, with the importing playbook's hosts instead of the imported playbook's hosts.

I can simply remove the hosts directive from the git playbook and call it via some other playbook, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way, or perhaps I'm just missing the right syntax.

Is there a simple way to import a playbook's tasks without its' hosts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hosts:` and `gather_facts:` can only exist in the top-most level of a play.

You should either

1. Write your playbook as a role which connects to the target server
2. Remove the conflicting statements and use `delegate_to:` when including your playbook tasks.